# angularjs set focus on specific cells - input cells of an ngrepeat

Tags: angularjs-directive

I have an angularjs page and i have a `ng-repeat` with a bunch of data and 2 inputs in the `ngrepeat` as well. Right now if i hit tab, it sends focus to the next cell (the links or the data in the table). I only want it to go to the next input. 
(
I have an ngrepeat with 6 cells of data and 2 inputs.
I want for every tab or enter, it should go to the next input.

So from line 1, input 1    to   line 1, input 2
Then line 2,input 1    to line 2, input 2
Then   line 3, input 1  to line 3, input 3

)

```
<td align="center">
    <ngform id="myForm" name="myForm">
        <input  ng-class="{ 'has-error': item.qtyToOrder>0 && filter.vendor !='' &&  item.price <=0}" type="number" name="myInput" ng-model="item.qtyToOrder" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-change="SavePO(item.qtyToReOrder, item.qtyToOrder,  {{$index}})" />                                             
    </ngform>
</td>

<!--<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="includePO" ng-model="item.includePO" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-change="SavePO(item.qtyToReOrder, item.qtyToOrder, item.includePO, {{$index}})" /></td>-->

<td align="right" ng-class="{ red: item.PctOver > 0 }">{{item.PctOver | number:2}}%</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

crazy easy solution.   just add tabindex = 1 for each input that you want to focus

```
<td align="center"><input id="qtyToReOrder"   tabindex="1" type="number" name="test" ng-model="item.qtyToReOrder" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-change="SavePO(item.qtyToReOrder, item.qtyToOrder,  {{$index}})" /></td>                                   
<td align="center">
<ngform id="myForm" name="myForm">
  <input id="qtyToOrder"  tabindex="1"  ng-class="{ 'has-error': item.qtyToOrder>0 && filter.vendor !='' &&  item.price <=0}" type="number" name="myInput" ng-model="item.qtyToOrder" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-change="SavePO(item.qtyToReOrder, item.qtyToOrder,  {{$index}})" /></ngform> </td>
```